# C++ precompiler conditionally include code

Tags: preprocessor

I have a few projects that share a lot of common code, but sometimes I need to not include certain parts of the common code depending on the project.

I've tried creating a separate file called project_names.hh, containing this:

```
// list of project names
#define FIRSTPROJECT 0
#define SECONDPROJECT 1

// PROJECT_NAME must be set to one of the above names in the project's main.cc file
#define PROJECT_NAME
```

Then in one of the projects' main files I do this:

```
#define PROJECT_NAME FIRSTPROJECT
```

The problem is that even though I include project_names.hh in another file, I can't seem to get this statement to compile:

```
#if PROJECT_NAME == FIRSTPROJECT
```

I get this error:

error: operator '==' has no left operand

Does anyone have a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Marlon

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've defined `PROJECT_NAME` to be the empty string with your line

```
#define PROJECT_NAME
```

you want to change it to

```
#define PROJECT_NAME FIRSTPROJECT
```

This needs to be in a header file that all the files of that project #include.

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `#define PROJECT_NAME` and instead use 
`-DPROJECT_NAME=FIRSTPROJECT` on the compiler command line for all the files in that project.  Note that if the same file is used in multiple projects, you'll need to compile it mulitple times with different options, and have it put the output in different places...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think this is the closest to what I want, but I don't want to put the #define PROJECT_NAME FIRSTPROJECT in project_names.hh because that file is included in all of the projects.  I wanted to do something like "declare" PROJECT_NAME and then set it in the main file of the particular project.  The idea with the project_names.hh file was so that each project could choose a project name from the list; if I do that on the compiler command line would it still be referring to the "FIRSTPROJECT" that was created in project_names.hh?

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your situation I would simply define either FIRSTPROJECT or SECONDPROJECT instead of setting PROJECT_NAME to either of those values.  I would then use `#ifdef` to check whether that value is set.

Answer (score 1):

rather than `#define PROJECT_NAME FIRSTPROJECT`,

use `#define FIRSTPROJECT`,

then check its existence with `#ifdef FIRSTPROJECT`

Answer (score 0):

You should include project_names.hh in the file in which you're running the `#if PROJECT_NAME == FIRSTPROJECT`.  The preprocessor might not have loaded and executed the statements setting `PROJCET_NAME` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because the PROJECT_NAME isn't set. You should check, which file is being compiled and check if the #define is set there.

It might help to set the define as a compiler option for the whole building process. For most compilers that I know (gcc, MSVC, clang, xlC), the compiler option would be

`-DPROJECT_NAME=FIRSTPROJECT`